# codeblocks debug output missing

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, output, codeblocks

I'm using ubuntu. When I compile a c file it works fine, but when I debug it show `warning gdb failed to set controlling terminal operation not permitted` and the output of the debug doesn't appear.
How can I fix this?

Comment: The project is a console application

Comment: This warning is harmless and normal. If you are not seeing something that you expect to see you will need to explain much better.

Comment: this happens for the default program that only print 'Hello world' and for every code that has an output inside; if I only compile and run it the output appears in the proper way... what kind of info would be usefull? thanks in advance

Comment: Have you set any breakpoints in the program? If not then console will close when the debugger exits, i.e. almost immediately

Comment: I set it, and the console remains opened, but there is no output on it

Comment: Sorrry, can't help then. Works fine for me.

Comment: im having the same problem when i switch to other terminals. are you using xterm as your program to launch console programs? (Settings->Environment). xterm works for me, other gnome-terminal(used to work) or konsole dont work.